# Foundation 6 Custom Build Generation Not Working

Tags: zurb-foundation, custom-build

I'm trying to generate a custom build of Foundation using:
https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/download.html/#customizeFoundation

I only unchecked Typography and Forms, and selected RTL Text Direction.
After submitting the form ("Download Custom Build"), I get this error:
ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/tmp/tmp.6.5.1.3379e8a88d76e4b6261174d9c9468f99.zip'

Has anyone ever experienced this sort of error?

With the Typography and Forms checked, a zip file is downloaded immediately.
However, I believe that is not the point of enabling a custom build.

Thanks,
Liron

Answer (score 0):

This is not a programming related question.

Please see https://github.com/foundation/foundation-sites/issues/11826

Comment: I was redirected here directly from Foundation's support page, wasn't paying attention that GitHub is for bugs etc. Thanks Daniel.